# Compiling files in folder to generate static library in Xcode

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I'm creating a static library. The static library has 5 components and common code shared by these components.

The folder structure of the source looks like this.

[image]

I need to generate a library using either one of the component, mixture of any components or all components.
I do not want to create targets for each of the combination...rather I want a script whcih takes number of copmonents as the input and generates the final archive for me.

How do we do this? I know that the script is the way to go....any help on this would be helpul for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think an ideal solution would be to create a static libs using [iOS Universal framework](https://github.com/kstenerud/iOS-Universal-Framework) you can create this as a separate project. Add all your components to this project. once you convert this to a static library you can import this to your main project using [cocoapods](https://github.com/cocoapods/cocoapods). You just need to create a pod spec file which provides path to your static library and coco-pods will do the rest for you.

Comment: The script should accept the components that Im interested to build and generate static library based on that.

Comment: Then you should use cocopod script to dump all components in a project , compile that to a static file and then another cocoapod script to integrate the static lib with your main project. I am assuming your components are native iOS code.

Comment: My task is to create only the library project. I have a static library project. This project has all the components code. So the final binary that gets created has all the components in it. Now I need a provision where in I should be able to create a library out of mixture of any components. All the components are independent of each other. eg: lib1 -> component1+ component5